# Trying to put a line inside an inner table into the next line

Tags: tables

I'm trying to put (Primary and Overlaid) on the bottom of the table into the next line but when I put \ the table dissapears

[image]

```
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}

%%% Multi line cells
\NewDocumentCommand\TB{O{c}O{c}m}{%
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#2@{}}#3\end{tabular}}
  
\newcommand\cmark{\ding{51}}
\newcommand\xmark{\ding{53}}
\newcommand\aggregation{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/aggregation_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\map{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/map_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\overlaid{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/overlaid_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\textt{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/text_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\primary{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/primary_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\visualization{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/visualization_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\image{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/image_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\video{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/video_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\transition{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/transition_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\progression{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/progression_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\pinStart{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/pinStart_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\pinEnd{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/pinEnd_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\effect{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/effect_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}
\newcommand\interactivity{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includesvg{dia/interactivity_icon.svg}}}   % \ding{110}}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.35}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}\color{black}
    Symbol & \TB{Design\\Language} & \TB{DataStoryDesign}  & Alternative / Considerations \\ \hline
    %
    Primary          & \cmark & \primary   & full support (Modality) \\ \hline
    Overlaid          & \cmark & \overlaid   & full support \\ \hline
    Affixed          & \xmark & no component   & Primary \\ \hline
    Storyline Foundation & \cmark & no component           & \TB{Degree (1, 1) on\\Grid Canvas} \\ \hline
    Block Formation      & \cmark & no component           & \TB{1, 2 Storylines on\\Grid Canvas} \\ \hline
    Group Composition    & \cmark & no component           & unidirectional (vertical) \\ \hline
    Frame Fixation       & \cmark & \pinStart\,\,\,\pinEnd & unidirectional (vertical)\\ \hline
    Progression          & \cmark & \progression           & full support \\ \hline
    Transition           & \cmark & \transition            & full support \\ \hline
    Aggregation          & \cmark & \aggregation           & full support \\ \hline
    Execution            & \xmark & no component           & \TB{Progression + Interactivity\\+ alternative path} \\ \hline
    Modality             & \cmark & \TB{\textt\,\,\,\image\,\,\,\visualization\\\video\,\,\,\map} & \TB{Text, Image, Visualization\\Video, Map (Primary and Overlaid)} \\ \hline
    Expressive Symbols  & \cmark & \effect\,\,\,\interactivity & Effect, Interactivity \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{DataStoryDesign adapted by design considerations}
  \label{tab:DataStoryDesignConsiderations}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile, there is no documentclass, no document environment and we don't have all your images.